# como mostrar una variable con diferentes resultados con JOptionPane

Tags: java, joptionpane

Tengo un código que muestra la notación desarrollada de una cifra
`EJEMPLO 1`: ingresas `4651` y el programa muestra la notación desarrollada
`1 50 600 4000`

y quiero mostrar toda la notación en una ventana de `JOptionPane` pero me sale asi:
1
aceptar
50
aceptar
600
aceptar
4000
aceptar

lo que quiero es que en una sola ventana me aparezca como el "EJEMPLO 1"
este es mi código:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class notacion {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         int num, n,R,f;
            byte potencia=0;
            num=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingresa un numero"));
            n=num;

            while(n>0) {
                R=n%10;
                n=n/10;
                f=R*(int)Math.pow(10,potencia);
                potencia=(byte) (potencia+1);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,+f);
                
                
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar una variable de tipo String que capture la primera salida de "f" y después acumule la segunda y así sucesivamente

```
int num, n,R;
     int f=0;
     String aux="";
        byte potencia=0;
        num=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingresa un numero"));
        n=num;

        while(n>0) {
            R=n%10;
            n=n/10;
            f=R*(int)Math.pow(10,potencia);
            potencia=(byte) (potencia+1);
          aux+=String.valueOf(+f)+"  ";   
          
            
        }

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,aux);
```

ingreso: 4561

salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias justo es lo que queria !!!

Comment: @JackC  Si te sirvio la respuesta da click en el check-in ✓